# How can I get parameters from URL in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a URL like this:

`http://www.chalklit.in/post.html?chapter=V-Maths-Addition%20&%20Subtraction&post=394`

How to get the value of parameter of chapter and post?

My URL contains '&' in the value of chapter parameter.

Comment: If your parameter have space or other white space character, then use POST method for send data.

Comment: There are few class for parsing  URI in java or android framework itself, what had you tried so far?

Comment: `Uri.parse().getQueryParameter()`

Comment: "My url contains '&' in the value of chapter parameter." Then it is broken. `&` needs to be url-encoded. AFAIK that should be %26 or something around that.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You can use the Uri class in Android to do this;  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.chalklit.in/post.html?chapter=V-Maths-Addition%20&%20Subtraction&post=394");
String server = uri.getAuthority();
String path = uri.getPath();
String protocol = uri.getScheme();
Set<String> args = uri.getQueryParameterNames();
```

Then you can even get a specific element from the query parameters as such;

```
String chapter = uri.getQueryParameter("chapter");  //will return "V-Maths-Addition "
```

Comment: chapter= " V-Maths-Addition "

Comment: my expected output was " V-Maths-Addition & Subtraction "

Comment: See comment above. You need to escape / url-encode `&`. It cannot be in the value. Where do you get that URL from. Do you have control over its construction?

Comment: Looks like your & is not correctly encoded, it should be %26 for an & otherwise it will be interpreted as a separator of parameters.

Comment: Beware that parameters of url with fragment (with # in it after a main part) not going to be parsed. One of the solutions for it is to replace "#" with "?"