# How to parse a URL without query paramterers?

Tags: android

This is my `URL` which i get after scanning a bar code :-

```
 https://www.dubrovniksecrets.com/use.php?101720131|02|03|2018.04.30|blah
```

How can i retrieve the values from the `URL`? Since there is no key i cannot use `getQueryParameterName()` to extract the value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40466295/9186864

Comment: what are your query parameter from above string exactly

Comment: The characters after ? are all parameters or values... I don't get a key in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to manually parse it. first cut off the first part, before `?`:

```
String url = "https://www.dubrovniksecrets.com/use.php?101720131|02|03|2018.04.30|b";
String paramsString = url.split("?")[1];
```

Then you can split the params:

```
String[] params = paramsString.split("|");
```

Now you have an array or the values.

Comment: Dangling metacharacter error on question mark symbol?

Comment: @Saathwik, have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: But i get individual numbers in the array... How can i get the entire value after `|` symbol?

Comment: @Saathwik, you've asked for `How can i retrieve the values from the URL`. I thought that it is exactly `individual numbers`. Can you clarify what you want to get form that URL?

Comment: I need the entire values after `|` symbol... ex : 101720131

Comment: @Saathwik,  `101720131` is not after "|". And if you want to get `101720131`, then you will get it in the first element of the `params` array using my code.

Comment: @pskink, and what should I do with your comment? What did you want to say with it?

Comment: @pskink, no need to what?

Comment: @pskink, same way there is no need for `Uri.parse`. Also how are you going to get `101720131` from it without `string.split()`?

Comment: @pskink, why removing your comments so fast?