# Android deep linking URI returned path segments

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I want to ask does android URI path segments support question marks? I have a url in the format

`www.blah.com/test?foo=123`

the matcher is something like

`<data android:pathPattern="/test.*"/>`

The URI returned is `www.blah.com/test?foo=123` but when I call `uri.lastPathSegments` it only returns `test` and cuts off `?foo=123`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466217/how-can-i-get-parameters-from-url-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `?foo=123` is not part of the URI path. It is called the *query*.
You should use `uri.query` or `uri.getQueryParameter("foo")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, Deeplink uri not support question marks.

For more info. Please check link: 
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking